# Penalized Bayesian quantile regression with LASSO and adaptive LASSO penalty

Tags: r, bayesian, lasso, quantile-regression, regularization

I have some questions about penalized Bayesian quantile regression with LASSO and adaptive LASSO penalty:

1. Would you give me a detailed outline for the formula, especially as used in Bayesian inference?
2. What package in R is easy to use and suitable for this topic?
3. Would you give me R code for running inference Bayesian quantile regression with LASSO penalty?

Comment: Does this method have a rationale? Is it justified? If you simply do a fully Bayes analysis, the shrinkage and sparsity is encouraged by appropriate choice of prior, and the quantiles immediately fall out of the posterior.